# how to change background and text color only in dvi display

Tags: color

Printed on paper, my LaTeX document has, of course, white background (= the paper) and black text (= the color of the black toner). By default, on my dvi screen output I see the same color allocation. Can it be changed? For example, I would like to see on my screen white text on a black or yellow beckground.

Comment: You could convert the dvi to pdf. Many pdf viewer have the ability to insert colours (white text on back) and some let you specify the background colour. Maybe there are dvi readers out there who can do the same?

Comment: The latex+dvi is very convenient for me. If I make a change in my tex file using VIM, and then type (from within VIM, without exiting)                                         :w! | !latex MyDocument                                                                                   then I instantly see the change on my screen.

Comment: you could do the same with pdflatex and get pdf rather than dvi (which is what  most people do), otherwise it depends on your dvi viewer, you have not said which you are using

Comment: I have MiKTeX Yap. I could use Acrobat Reader for pdf, but this would be far more slower and troublesome for me.

Comment: On a Linux or macOS with XQuartz you can use `xdvi` like this `xdvi -bg DarkSeaGreen  Foo.dvi &` to set the background color but so far I have not yet found a setting to change the ink color.  For color names see [X11_color_names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names). You can also use `xdvi -bg '#CC0066'` hexadecimal syntax.  I agree dvi can be extremely useful espacially to scroll pages fast.

Comment: Besides the `latex+dvipdfmx` route produces sometimes significantly (ten times!) smaller PDFs, due to font compression, but for that you can use `xelatex` too.

Comment: As per dark mode for PDFs I was also interested into this and only commercial products seem to offer it.  However, you can use Firefox built-in pdf viewer, following [this](https://connect.mozilla.org/t5/ideas/dark-mode-for-embedded-pdf-viewer/idc-p/47950/highlight/true#M27901).  It works but beware it of course inverts all colors of embedded graphics.

Comment: @user691586 The pdfviewer of texstudio also offers a dark mode with inverted colours. Skim follows the os and can automatically invert colours if in dark mode.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz good to know thanks!

Comment: @user691586 KOReader also offers a night mode with inverted colours

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I did not know about Skim because my os is too old on both my machines and does not offer night mode beyond suppressing supposedly nefarious blue wavelengths

Comment: @user691586 `xdvi -fg red -bg yellow sample2e.dvi` [works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tTJo.png).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it works for me too and I don't know how I did not see the `-fg` in the xdvi man page...